# How to trace dynamoDB transactions

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudtrail

We can see read transactions are breaking dynamodb threshold. I would like to see what query is making this high utilization. I am looking for some report like AWR in oracle.
Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

[DynamoDB streams](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) would be a great way to monitor activity on the a table but this won't help for monitoring reads. This will most likely have to be handled inside your application code.

If you're using the aws-sdk you can turn on logging

- [java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-logging.html)
- [node.js](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-configuring.html)

If you're using an abstraction on top of the aws-sdk for example [vogels](https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels) then you can just enable logging in that library too.

I wrote about my experience of predicting the required RCU [here](http://clarkie.io/devops/2016/04/24/load-testing-dynamodb.html)